# Is it okay to make a loop of LED strips?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, led-strip

I have 10 m of RGB LED strips (common anode) and want to put it around my room. I realized on testing that the "far of" LED s were very dim compared to those that were "electrically" near the driver circuit. Would it be okay to loop back the common positive and ground to the starting point. Basically loop back the power and ground rails? Is there any problem if I am driving them with a PWM signal of around 1 KHz?
edit 1: I asked the last part because a loop would might create some EMI due to the 1KHz PWM signal running through it.

Answer (score 4):

If you connect your positive supply cable to one side of the LED Strip and the GND cable on the far end of the LED Strip the LEDs will be the same brightness.
A antenna for a 1 KHz signal must at least be 75km long so i would not expect any problems in terms of radiated emissions. Since you are using a square wave you must consider the slope of the signal though, which you can control by controlling how fast your switch turns on (eg. with a gate resistor when using a MOSFET).

Answer (score 2):

Making it a ring circuit would not be that bad, assuming you can do it neatly ;)

As for emissions, although 1kHz is not that high a frequency, if the edges are sharp that 1kHz will be producing some very high frequency harmonics. As such, it may be prudent to limit the edges using some form of high frequency filter on the feed output, if it does not do that already.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should be injecting power at 2.5m, but in a pinch you can simply provide power at both ends, like you describe. This reduces the effect of the high resistance of the FPC.

As to EMI from a 1khz pwm, it's unlikely to affect anything.

Comment: Providing ground and positive supply at both Ends would result in dim LEDs in the middle

Comment: But less total dimness than the alternative.

Comment: @jogi and how is yours is electrically different?

Comment: When power is connected to both sides and the cable length (or more accurate, the resistance of the cabling) is the same for both sides there is no difference. You are right, but why use 4 instead of 2 cables.

Comment: @jogi OP is making a circle. So there is only a single pair of power cables.